# Ruby on Rails omniauth cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, session-cookies, omniauth, remember-me

I'm using omniauth to provide Facebook authentication facility in my ruby on rails application. I set up default expire date for cookies 20 minutes by following code:

```
Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '_rails-omniauth_session', expire_after: 20.minutes
```

Now I want to add "remember me" feature to my application. In that situation I want to update expire date for '_rails-omniauth_session' cookie. However, I couldn't find how to do that. I have tried some instinctive code examples but couldn't make it.

How can I update expire date set by omniauth in my application. In general term how can I add remember me facility with omniauth.

Thanks.